# How to call static methods from name in string variable in C#?

Tags: c#

I have strings with a math function names. E.g. Sin, Abs, Max ...

How can I call for example Math.Sin(arg) in a way where I can specify the Sin part based on a variable?

Comment: Did you try reflection?

Comment: Have you take a look at extension methods?

Comment: No, I just started C#. Do you have an entry point/link?

Comment: You could use reflection, but for a simple case like choosing the function from a set, it is simpler to use a switch statement.

Comment: If you have just started C#, instead of doing such things, spend time on learning the language IMHO.

Comment: You wrote in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289466/how-to-call-object-methods-from-name-in-string-variable-in-c#comment108424671_61289466) _Do you have an entry point/link?_ Is there something preventing you from searching the Internet? [C# Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) and [C# Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use reflection

```
var concreteType = typeof(Math);
var result = concreteType.GetMethod("Sin").Invoke(null, new object[] { numbers });
```

Comment: Since Math.Sin is a static method, you must `.Invoke(null, ...)`